# How to get horizontal scrolling with the div element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this div element:

```
    <div id="tl"  style="float:right;width: 400px; height:100px; background-color:Green; overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;">

        <div id='demo' style="float:left;height:90px;"> dsadsad </div>
        <div id='demo' style="float:left;height:90px;"> dsadsad </div>

    </div>
```

The div demo will copy by the code more times inside tl div.
I want to Horizontal Scrolling the tl div.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the value of the `id` attribute should be unique.

Comment: @ nikc iths only for the example you can consider it for other div with float left

Comment: At first glance, that markup looks like it should work.  If you do overflow-x:auto; it will not show the scroll bar if they are not needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your "demo" divs, change float: left to display: inline-block; then it should work.

Also, see Stack Overflow question "[How to get Floating DIVs inside fixed-width DIV to continue horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015809/how-to-get-floating-divs-inside-fixed-width-div-to-continue-horizontally)" for more suggestions...

EDIT: as timhessel says in the comments below, Internet Explorer 6/7 won't accept inline-block for div elements so you need to use span elements for the "demo" divs instead as they are intrinsically inline by default.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 don't accept inline-block for divs or other elements that have an insintric display value of block.

Comment: this is true, so the "demo" divs should be changed to span elements instead.

Comment: hi i changed it to 
<span style="float:left;height:100px;" >some text</span>
it also not working as it should there is Horizontal Scrolling but i can't scroll

Comment: you have to change float:left to be display: inline-block;

Comment: as well as changing the div to be a span. It works for me in Safari.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research, and trying out a few things, I believe what you're trying to do, cannot really be achieved without having an extra container, which has a fixed width, as floating elements stack themselves according to the size of the container.

The CSS:

```
    div.horiz-container {
        border: 1px solid silver;
        height: 100px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        whitespace: nowrap;
        width: 400px;
    }

    div.horiz-container div.content {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        height: 100px;
        width: 500px;
    }

    div.horiz-container p {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="horiz-container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem</p
        <p>ipsum</p>
        <p>dolor</p>
        <p>sit</p>
        <p>amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See live demo:
http://nikc.kapsi.fi/dev/html/misc/horiz-scroll.html

Also take a look at a similar question asked before: 
[HTML Divs, Columns, Horizontal Scroll Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278796/html-divs-columns-horizontal-scroll-bar)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, I have been using the following to do what I think you want.

http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html

Comment: hi it's not what i meant i only want the user can Horizontal Scrolling div, but thanks