# Divs next to each other, with size, no linebreak

Tags: html, css

I want many little div-s next to each other, with no linebreak:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;">

<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>

</div>
```

the problem is, the width works, but it goes to new line if overflows, so no scroll horizontally.

Comment: I think what you are looking for has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321851/how-to-get-horizontal-scrolling-with-the-div-element and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015809/how-to-get-floating-divs-inside-fixed-width-div-to-continue-horizontally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with `white-space` & `display:inline-block;`. Write like this:

```
.parent{
 white-space:nowrap;
overflow:scroll;
}
.parent > div{
 display:inline-block;
 white-space:normal;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/

Comment: That is the best way to do it. I *would* put a min-width on `.parent`. Another point to keep in mind is to avoid whitespace between the divs in the `.parent`, or else you may end up with 1 `ch`of vertical space between the single divs.

Comment: @UmairP it's not work in IE6 but for IE7 there is an hack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block

Answer (score 1):

The width of your general container in which these divs will be placed needs to be set to "width:100%", so that i can adapt to the growing size.

Comment: but it then ignores the "width" value

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script for you.

Not sure if that's exactly what you want.

http://jsbin.com/anoran/edit#javascript,html

UPDATED:

http://jsbin.com/anoran/2/edit

Comment: this also puts to new line if there are too much inner div

Comment: yes, you need to adjust width of outer div, if you want all divs in single row.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; width:100%|400px">
    <div style="width:10000px">


<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 40px;"></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

worked in chrome!