# Inline Span Elements inside of Horizontal Scrolling DIV

Tags: html

I'm hoping someone here can help me out with this simple task. I'm looking to place several span elements inside of a horizontal scrolling DIV. I originally had DIVs inside of the horizontal DIV but was told this:

> CSS rendering is not going to work on inline block elements. They will always wrap unless the containing DIV is set to a width value large enough to let all inline block elements float left.

I switched to  elements but I'm still having trouble with them wrapping. I was sent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321851/how-to-get-horizontal-scrolling-with-the-div-element), which led me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015809/how-to-get-floating-divs-inside-fixed-width-div-to-continue-horizontally), and then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431101/horizontal-scroll-in-div-with-many-small-divs-inside-no-text) on my own. None of these are working for me.

The page in question is here: http://melanie-patterson.com/fashion-bloggers/

As of now, this is my HTML:

```
<div class="SpanContainer">
<span class="block">
<img src="http://melanie-patterson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/dlsw4.png" alt="" />
<br>description</span>

<span class="block">
<img src="http://melanie-patterson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/leprettystellar.png">
<br>DESCRIPTION</span>

<span class="block">
<img src="http://melanie-patterson.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/simonett.png" alt="" />
<br>DESCRIPTION
</span>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.format_text {
width:750px;
height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#SpanContainer {
width:1000px;
height: 600px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
margin:auto;
float: left;
}

span.block {
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
}
```

I don't know why I'm having so many issues with this! Any help would be wonderful. Also, let me just add that I'm using Wordpress, and specifically, the 'Thesis' theme by DIYThemes.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `div id="SpanContainer"`
You used *class* instead of *id*